# How to return the correct type from a chained method?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I have a service with two methods that I'd like to method chain and get typed information for.

```
const result = FirstMethod().SecondMethod();
```

Methods are defined like so:

```
FirstMethod(): any {
 // do some stuff
 return this;
} 

SecondMethod(): MyAwesomeType {
   return this.getMyAwesomeValue();
}
```

The problem is that result comes back as type any with no type information. I would expect that because my second method returns `MyAwesomeType` that i'd be able to get type information for that.

Obviously I can coerce the result to be the type that I might expect, but it doesn't provide much type safety if for example I were to put the wrong type there. What could I do?

Comment: Why does `FirstMethod()` return a value of type `any`?  It should probably be returning a value of type `this`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [Advanced Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html). Telling the compiler that you're returning `any` screws up type inference *unless* you encapsulate it in a class:

```
class Fooby {
    //instead of returning any here, consider returning `this`
    foo(): any /*returns Fooby instance*/ {
        return this;
    }

    betterFoo(): this /*returns Fooby instance, more explicit*/ {
        return this;
    }

    bar(): number {
        return 3;
    }
}

console.log(
    new Fooby().foo().bar()//3
);
```

Will not work as a *function*:

```
foo2(): any {
    return this;
}

bar2(): number {
    return 3;
}

console.log(
    foo2().bar2()
);
```

Answer (score 1):

I suppose this depends on your development environment, but in WebStorm it helped to define the return type of the first method.

[image]

@Rafael's answer says the same thing, but I it is think more explicit to label the return type as the class name rather than `this`.